# Thymeleaf: How to exclude outer tag when using th:each?

Tags: java, template-engine, thymeleaf

The Thymeleaf 2.1.4 official doc demonstrates the `for each` usage as below:

```html
 <tr th:each="prod : ${prods}" th:class="${prodStat.odd}? 'odd'">
    <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
    ...
 </tr>
```

It generates one `<tr>` in each iteration, which is perfect fit in this situation. However in my case I don't need the outer tag (here, `<tr>`).

---

My use case is to generating `<bookmark>` tag in a recursive way, no other tags include, and a `<bookmark>` tag must contain a name and href attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>

<div th:fragment="locationBookmark(location)">
    <bookmark th:each="map : ${location.subMaps}">
        <bookmark th:name="${map.name}"
                  th:href="'#'+${map.id}" th:include=":: locationBookmark(${map})">
        </bookmark>
    </bookmark>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the including side:

```html
<bookmark th:include="bookmark : locationBookmark(${rootLocation})"/>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide sample of tag you want to not close by outer tag?

Comment: @PavelUvarov My use case added, see my question.

Comment: Let me guess: you want to make n-leveled child tags? I think so because: bookmark is not html tag and because it is not recommended to not close tags with content. If I'm right - you should create and use some sub-template in recursive manner. I'm not to good in ThymeLeaf to say how you should do it, but I surely know that this is possible - please look their docs carefully.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Even if it can be done using `th:remove="tag"` I would suggest you use [th:block](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag)

```
<th:block th:each="map : ${location.subMaps}">
   <bookmark th:name="${map.name}"
        th:href="'#'+${map.id}" th:include=":: locationBookmark(${map})">
    </bookmark>
</th:block>
```

Comment: @Xipo I corrected <th:block> to </th:block>.. hope that is correct for all Thymeleaf versions, but since XML is underlying...

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to solve the problem, it's easy, just add`th:remove="tag"` to the outer tag will do.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what the OP asked for but it could be useful to some:

A tag can also be removed **conditionally**:

```
<div class="myConditionalOuterDiv" th:remove="${condition}? tag"}> 
    <span> I'm always there </span>
</div>
```

This removes the parent element but leaves the children elements in place.

Source [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-template-fragments)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DIV` tag or any other HTML tag to loop with. This will not generate a `TR` tag. But for the table to render correctly you need to have the `TD` tags inside of `TR` tags.

```
<div th:each="prod : ${prods}" th:class="${prodStat.odd}? 'odd'">
    <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is removing the tag completely, rather than changing its name.